# Set Server Variable in IIS

Tags: iis, server-variables

I dont have much knowledge on IIS Webserver. The Scenario is, I have a cognos Analytics installed has IIS as Webserver(IBM Tool) execute the link in browser which set the "CAM_Passport" as one of the cookie in browser. CAM_Passport is much like a token for the User cookie which is used for other application for single sign on.

I would like to set this "CAM_Passport" as a Server-Varaible in IIS. I have another application which need to read the "CAM_PAssport" for logging-in.

Kindly suggest me some detailed input on this. Thanks

Comment: The information above is incomplete, so no answer can be given. SSO requires much more than setting a variable. For example, where does the value of that cookie come from? The vendor of your SSO solution should have documentation on how to configure it correctly for typical web servers (including IIS), which should be your primary source.

Comment: you could set a custom server variable by using the iis URL rewrite rule module. in iis URL rewrite module Under Action's select View Server Variables under 'Manager Server variables'. Click on Add from Actions and type in CAM_Passport on the Add Server Variable dialog box. Next click on Edit under Inbound Rules under Actions. Under the Server Variables section click on Add. From the Set Server variables, the dialog box selects the server variables that we just created CAM_Passport from the drop-down. Set the value. Click on ok and restart the webserver.

Comment: SSO working for Cognos Analytics Application but I would like to use the cam_passport cookie to set in another application for logging in without giving the credentials. Is it possible, if so kindly guide me.